# Generate file:// URL for local file or directory

Tags: filesystems, url

I have a local directory and want to share a clickable link that will open the user's default file browser.

How to generate an URL of the `file://` protocol for a given local filename?

```
some_program /foo/bar    # file:///foo/bar
some_program "/föö bar"    # file:///f%C3%B6%C3%B6%20bar
some_program "$( realpath . )"    # link to local directory
```

I found some hints for the reverse operation utilizing naive replacement commands in `sed` what fails for filenames with non-alphanumeric characters like whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

The Perl module [`URI::file`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::file) supports this:

```
$ perl -MURI::file -E'say URI::file->new($_) for @ARGV' /foo/bar
file:///foo/bar
```